# In a group if $ab=e$ then is it always true that $ba=e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse

I think it's not true. But since in a group, inverse for each element exist then, we can write:

$ab=e$
Multiplying by $a^{-1}$ on both sides
$b=a^{-1}e=a^{-1}$

This implies that $ba=e$

Am I missing out something? Thankyou for any help or hint.

Comment: If you multiply $ab=e$ on the *left* by $a^{-1}$ (*not* "both sides") you get $b=a^{-1}$. If you *then* multiply $b=a^{-1}$ by $a$ on the right you get $ba=e$.

Comment: $ba=bae=babb^{-1}=beb^{-1}=bb^{-1}=e$

Comment: This is true if $a$ and $b$ are elements of a group and $e$ denotes the identity element of that group. Perhaps you should have said that rather than leaving it to the reader to guess what you are talking about?

Comment: In general, for every $a$ and $b$ in a group, we get $ba=b(ab)b^{-1}$ (which boils down to $ba=ab$ *if* the group is abelian). So, what does heppen if, for some $a,b$ in the group, $ab=e$?